# T-SQL Sort Hierarchical data in a tree structure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some dummy employee/manager data and I want to present it in an order that represents a tree like structure.
I have already figured out how to calculate the "OrgLevel" using CTEs so have hard coded it in my dummy data.

Now I am just struggling with how to sort it in my desired order so that it comes out alphabetically but employees are sorted directly after their manager. This is a visual representation of how it should look if I have the sorting correct.

[image]

```
SELECT 'Bart Simpson' AS EmployeeName, 'Marge Simpson' AS ManagerName, 5 AS OrgLevel UNION
SELECT 'Bruce' AS EmployeeName, 'Mr Burns' AS ManagerName, 2 AS OrgLevel UNION
SELECT 'Donald' AS EmployeeName, 'Mr Burns' AS ManagerName, 2 AS OrgLevel UNION
SELECT 'Homer Simpson' AS EmployeeName, 'Bruce' AS ManagerName, 3 AS OrgLevel UNION
SELECT 'Lisa Simpson' AS EmployeeName, 'Marge Simpson' AS ManagerName, 5 AS OrgLevel UNION
SELECT 'Maggie Simpson' AS EmployeeName, 'Marge Simpson' AS ManagerName, 5 AS OrgLevel UNION
SELECT 'Marge Simpson' AS EmployeeName, 'Homer Simpson' AS ManagerName, 4 AS OrgLevel UNION
SELECT 'Mr Burns' AS EmployeeName, '' AS ManagerName, 1 AS OrgLevel UNION
SELECT 'The Cat' AS EmployeeName, 'Mr Burns' AS ManagerName, 2 AS OrgLevel
```

Comment: Derived how? What logic should be used?

Comment: Aside: You might want to use [`Space`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/space-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for indenting: `Space( OrgLevel * 2 ) + EmployeeName as EmployeeName`.

Comment: I need the data to be sorted alphabetically by name, but starting with a manager at OrgeLevel 1, then any managers or employees below them before then next OrgLevel 1 person.

Comment: @TommySharp You should edit your question and show the exact output you expect here.

Comment: Homer Simpson reports to Bruce, not Donald... So your sorting is not right...

Comment: Have reworded and provided a better version of the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

For a more general solution, you may look into using a recursive hierarchical query.  Using a recursive CTE approach, you can articulate logic which will space each descendant in the tree appropriately.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT EmployeeName, CAST(EmployeeName AS varchar(255)) AS IndentedName, OrgLevel
    FROM Employees
    WHERE OrgLevel = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT e1.EmployeeName, CAST(REPLICATE('    ', e1.OrgLevel) + e1.EmployeeName AS varchar(255)), e1.OrgLevel
    FROM Employees e1
    INNER JOIN cte e2
        ON e2.EmployeeName = e1.ManagerName AND
           e2.OrgLevel = e1.OrgLevel - 1
)

SELECT IndentedName
FROM cte
ORDER BY OrgLevel;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks but with your suggestion it does not sort records in tht correct order... Homer Simpson reports to Donald and not The Cat so should come after Donald etc...